# Reuse ranges in ggplot for several plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use R for my data analysis and found `ggplot` quite nice to use. But there is one feature I cannot get to work.

I have several plots and working on the same relying on the same dataframe `df`, that should all have the same `xmin`s and `xmax`s.

My stripped code looks something like this (with dummy data):

```
import(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(c(0.3,0.1,0.2),c(0.2,0.1,0.3),c(0.3,0.2,0.1),c(0.5,0.6,0.22))
names(df)=c("X1","Y1","X2","Y2")
pdf("Test.pdf")
plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = Y1, xmin=-0.02, xmax=0.02, ymin=-0.02, ymax=0.02))+geom_path()
print(plot)
plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x = X2, y = Y2, xmin=-0.02, xmax=0.02, ymin=-0.02, ymax=0.02))+geom_path()
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

In my case I have even more columns like `X3,Y3,...`, so that there is a lot of repetition.

All the time I have to copy all these `xmin` and `xmax` variables, so there is a lot of clutter in my code.

Is there a way in `ggplot`, that I can factor out these ranges in a common object `ranges`and then adding it to `aes(x=Xp, y=Yp)+ranges`?

Comment: Can you please include data or plots that you generate in your question? It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Wait. I'll make you a complete example.

Comment: I find it slightly strange that your code works in the first place, because `geom_point` doesn't 'understand' (sensu help text) the `xmin` / `xmax` aesthetics. Check `?lims`: "You can also supply limits that are larger than the data. This is useful if you want to match scales across different plots". Just put the desired limits in a `list` and add to the individual plots. E.g. `lims <- list(xlim(0, 350), ylim(5, 40))`. `p1 + lims`; `p2 + lims`

Comment: I just copied it directly from my RStudio and it worked. Wasn't aware of lims. I'll check this.

Comment: ...and now following your edit, I see that you have your data in wide format. Make your `ggplot` life easier and convert it to long format. To avoid "a lot of repetition". Tons of posts on this topic on SO. When your data is in the proper format, you may have _one_ call to `ggplot`. If you use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` the axis limits are the same for each individual plot by default.

Comment: Cool! Your tip worked. I can now replace lim in every line. Maybe I need to undestand what long format ist. I'm using R only every now and then.

Comment: Yes, if you plan to do more than one ggplot in your life, you should take your time to understand the concept of 'wide' and 'long' data, and how to convert between the two. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh @Henrik's comment into an answer, you can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to convert the data to long format, like so:

```
long_df <-
  df %>%
  gather(X, Xval, starts_with("X")) %>%
  gather(Y, Yval, starts_with("Y"))
```

This returns the data in long format, like so:

```
    X Xval  Y Yval
1  X1  0.3 Y1 0.20
2  X1  0.1 Y1 0.10
3  X1  0.2 Y1 0.30
4  X2  0.3 Y1 0.20
5  X2  0.2 Y1 0.10
6  X2  0.1 Y1 0.30
7  X1  0.3 Y2 0.50
8  X1  0.1 Y2 0.60
9  X1  0.2 Y2 0.22
10 X2  0.3 Y2 0.50
11 X2  0.2 Y2 0.60
12 X2  0.1 Y2 0.22
```

Where there is a row for each X/Y pairing. This allows you to make a single call to `ggplot` and plot all of the pairs:

```
ggplot(
  long_df
  , aes(x = Xval, y = Yval)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(X~Y)
```

gives

[image]

Or, if you only want the 1/2 pairs (`parse_number` is from `readr`, another part of the `tidyverse` packages):

```
long_df %>%
  mutate(Xnum = parse_number(X)
         , Ynum = parse_number(Y)) %>%
  filter(Xnum == Ynum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Xval, y = Yval)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~X+Y)
```

gives:

[image]

You could, alternatively, filter by any other pairing criteria you want. E.g. to get X1-Y2 and X2-Y1:

```
long_df %>%
  filter(
    (X == "X1" & Y == "Y2") |
      (X == "X2" & Y == "Y1")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Xval, y = Yval)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~X+Y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice example! I'll need some time to digest it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for producing a series of individual plots is to save the plot to an object and modify it only where it's necessary:

```
library(tidyverse) # or magrittr and ggplot2 at the least

p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X1, Y1)) +
  geom_path() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.2, 0.6), ylim = c(-0.2, 0.6))
```

You should use `coord_cartesian()` if you only want to zoom the plot and not cut out values.

Now let's change only the columns we want to draw:

```
p1 + aes(X2, Y2)
```

You can also change the data on a plot easily with `%+%`, as explained in http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/gg-add.html, so if you had another dataset called `df2` where the column names were the same, you could do:

```
p1 %+% df2
```